# Quickselect time complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I want to calculate the average number of comparison in quickselect algorithm. I know the average runtime is O(n), but need to know the constant too.  So surf the net to find answer, but I got confused when read different solutions.
Is it 4n? 3n? or what?
Can anyone help me?
thanks in advance

Comment: A coefficient for *n* only makes sense when you have a unit of measure (a microsecond?), but then it still depends on the power of the device you run it on, so it is quite useless as a measurement. *O(n)* is all you can say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is `O(n)`. The constant about which you are interested depends on the way that partition is being is done. It varies for different pivot. That's why it's `cn` where `c` is constant. (it can be 4 or 3 or 5 etc).

Worst case it can be `O(n^2)` average case `O(n)`. That is all you can say for sure.